# Initialize class reference

Tags: string, class, reference, null, initialization

I get `null` value of `instrumentRented`
when I run

```
public class RentalAgreement
{
    private MusicalInstrument instrumentRented;

public RentalAgreement(Customer renter, 
    RentalDate dateRented, 
    MusicalInstrument instrumentRented){            
        customer = renter;
        rentalDate = dateRented;
        instrumentRented = instrumentRented;
```

How to initialize `MusicalInstrument` reference in `RentalAgreement`?

Comment: I do not understand what you ran. Where is the main method? Is this Java?

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.instrumentRented = instrumentRented;`

Since the parameter has the same name as the field attribute, you need to prefix with an explicit `this` to specify the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate a class with the new operator.

So somehwere in your code must do

```
instrumentRented = new MusicalInstrument();
```

**before** you access it. After you have done this you can execute functions from that class.

```
instrumentRented.doSomething();
```

In the above code you seem to pass it in in the constructor, so this means the caller has to instantiate it.

However I would advise to adopt a naming convention where you can see if a variable is a class member or a local variable. In your above code the local variable has the same name as the parameter, so it will not be set as a member variable, instead you assign it to itself. You might get a warning about this, depending on the evironment (Not sure about this but Eclipse definitely warns somethign like this). This is called shadowing, so what you need to do is:

```
this.instrumentRented = instrumentRented;
```

Comment: do you know how to provide get and set method for an ArrayList?